# How to (programatically) remove a certificate from a PEM file?

Tags: openssl, lets-encrypt

I have an old version of an application that is using it's own cert store, however the expired DST ROOT X3 is still in the cert store causing issues when it's encountering letsencrypt certificates.

I manually tested that removing the expired root from its cert store fixes the issues, however I need to constantly deploy and redeploy this application in a fairly complicated setup, which means that after deployment I need a programmatic way (say openssl command) to remove this certificate from the cert store.

Is there such a capability in openssl, or any other smart / hacky way to remove it?

The cert store is a plain pem file.